# how to locate an element inside expanded list

Tags: python, selenium

I have a little problem. I am writing an automatic test, that has to go to webpage, enter some keys to search, then go to advanced search options, choose one from a list and search. The point is, that I have absolutely no idea on how to locate element on a list. It looks like this: http://www.e-podroznik.pl/public/searcherFinal.do. If you click on "więcej opcji" you'll se a list of options about journey. My question: how to locate element on this expanded "więcej opcji"-list using python selenium? I have tried everything, from find_element_by* to execute_script; nothing works. I get errors like 'unable to locate element', 'compound not permitted'  etc.

The HTML:

```
<div class="advanced-searcher dNone more-options" style="display: block;">

    <label class="lblDepartureArrival"></label>
    <label class="lblRadio frmButtonFlat lblDeparture"></label>
    <label class="lblRadio frmButtonFlat lblDeparture"></label>
    <span class="lblOmmit"></span>
    <label class="lblCaptionCarrierType"></label>
    <label class="lblCarrierType lblCheckbox frmButtonFlat carrierType-bus"></label>
    <label class="lblCarrierType lblCheckbox frmButtonFlat carrierType-rail"></label>
    <label class="lblCarrierType lblCheckbox frmButtonFlat carrierType-aut"></label>
    <label class="lblCarrierType lblCheckbox frmButtonFlat carrierType-city"></label>
    <label class="lblCaptionJourneyMode"></label>
    <span class=""></span>
    <span class=""></span>
    <span class=""></span>
    <label class="lblSort">
        <span class="fldCaption">

            Sortuj według:

        </span>
        <span class="fldContainer">
            <select id="sortTypeV_1399324651976" name="formCompositeSearchingResults.formCompositeSearcherFinalH.sortTypeV" style="display: none;">
                <option selected="selected" value="departure"></option>
                <option value="time"></option>
                <option value="price"></option>
            </select>
            <span class="frmDropdown"></span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <a class="lnkSwitchSearcherType" title="Wyszukiwarka zaawansowana" href="/public/searcher.do?method=task&advanced=false"></a>

</div>
```

I specifically need to expand list:

```
"<select id="sortTypeV_1399324651976" name="formCompositeSearchingResults.formCompositeSearcherFinalH.sortTypeV" style="display: none;">" and then click "<option value="time"></option>
```

This doesn't work:

```
def do_the_advanced_search(self): 
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm_1399323992507"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/label[3]').click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

neither this:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('sortTypeV_1399324651976').style=='display: inline block';")
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the part that contains the dropdown, you can use this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a>span.imageSprite.sprite-label-left").click()
```

Then you can use `execute_script` to set the value:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('current').value = 'Najkrótszy czas';")
```

The `select` itself is hidden via `style=display:none;` so it cannot be manipulated directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! 

right now, everything works fine, yhe option changes from "czas odjazdu" (default one) to "najkrótszy czas" (the desired one), but the searcher still does the search by the default option. What is so wrong with this page? :(